# How to fetch record by address

Tags: sqlite

How do I select customer records by address.

```
var allUsers = db.Query<Customer>("Select * From Customer Where lower(CompanyName) =?" + " AND lower(Address) like ?",  Class1.Company.ToLower() , txtAddr.Text.ToLower() + "%");

Example:
Address : 123, Berry Road, ontario
```

If I used above select statement and I type berry in textbox Addr, the search will return 0.

is it correct to use lower()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var allUsers = db.Query<Customer>("Select * From Customer Where lower(CompanyName) =?" + " AND lower(Address) like ?",  Class1.Company.ToLower() , "%" +txtAddr.Text.ToLower() + "%");
```

That you'll get `lower(Address) like '%berry%'` intsead of `lower(Address) like 'berry%'`.

Here is the <kbd>[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1d6eb/1)</kbd>.

Comment: % word % will match against the Address that contain : ,(Comma), (') number, postCode and other. will 1000 customer records slow down this select-statement? What other characters or symbols will not work for this Select statement?

Comment: I really cannot get what's your concern? 1) If you want your sample data returned, `'berry%'` could only return the address with `berry` begins. 2) you can add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query if you worry about 1000 customer will slow down. 3) If the first condition `lower(CompanyName) =?` fails, nothing will be returned. Suggest you test those conditions with SqlFiddle demo supplied in the answer. If you have further questions, update the input data and querys.

Comment: Your solution works. I just want to confirm when using %berry% to match an address string containing comma, (') and other illegal character, will this cause any issue. say to match %berry%  in " 123,berry's road, Blvd, (#003) ,Ontario". Thanks